# Grapes unable to resolve an item from maven-central

Tags: groovy, ivy

Groovy's Grapes isn't finding something that I can see quite plainly in Maven-central. Groovy installed via Homebrew (and is up to date)

```
$ grape --version
Groovy Version: 2.4.6 JVM: 1.9.0-ea

$ rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/com/jcraft
$ rm -rf ~/.ivy2/cache/
$ rm -rf ~/.groovy/grapes/
$ grape -V resolve com.jcraft jzlib 1.1.3
```

Yields:

```
Error in resolve:
    Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: com.jcraft#jzlib;1.1.3!jzlib.jar]
```

Note, a bazillion builds for Maven and Gradle (and other grapes) are able to pull artifacts down from 'central' and I explicitly have no proxy for this.

I've no idea what is wrong... :-(

#### Update: Mar 20, 2016:

Issue raised with Groovy team (incl. workaround) - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7776

Comment: Hmm. I was able to run a on of the jlib examples as a groovy script and using the ` @Grab(group='com.jcraft', module='jzlib', version='1.1.3')` Grapes annotation. Have you tried that or can you?

Comment: That's how I encountered the issue. I figured i'd turn it into a CLI example to make it easier for people to reproduce.  You know "Error grabbing Grapes" reports go back a number of years in. Meaning I wonder if this is a tricky to reproduce error and the core team have never got it to a place where they can add break-points.